# Display XY data on computer

Tags: arrays, matrices, square-grid

I would like to experiment with displaying the output of an analog to digital converter on computer. Samples of the ADC output would determine the intensity of one pixel.

The input to the ADC is an array of XY wires, with each XY junction representing a pixel.

I can work with such circuitry, but I don't know where to start in displaying the data on a computer monitor. Kindly point me in the right direction.

Comment: I'm not completely sure this is the right place for this question. Anyway, there are probably *many* possible ways to achieve what you ask for. Perhaps if you add a bit more details we'd be able to point you to the easiest one. What format is the input in? Is it coming from a file or do you somehow need to interface directly with the ADC? In the former case, how is the data structured? In the latter what's the communication protocol? Also do you need the image to update in real time as new data comes in (what's the rate?)? Which OS are you using? Do you have any experience with programming?

Comment: I appreciate your comment, Steven. Since posting this question, I have come to the conclusion that the most likely way to accomplish the above is to use a dedicated display run by a raspberry pi. It is more amenable to hacking than is the PC-monitor interface.

Comment: If the Pi isn't fast enough, it's also possible to make a VGA signal yourself without too much difficulty. An ADC would not be involved in your part of the circuit, since VGA is analog!

Comment: Thanks, user253751. I will keep that in mind.